# Change button link after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<button>` element inside a `<form>` that has `onsubmit='return false'` so if I try to link the button inside an `<a>` tag it won't be called. Right now if you click that button it will execute an animation, and since `onsubmit` returns false the page isn't reloaded, but I want that same button to open `https://google.com` i.e. after it has been clicked once, I've tried adding the attributes `method=GET action=google.com` to the form using JQuery 
once the button is clicked but it opens google on the first click, not in the second one. Any ideas?

```
<form class="box" id="box" onsubmit="return false">
  <button class="sign-button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will have to be done in JavaScript. In the example below I've used [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to make it simpler.

```
var checkedAlready = false;

$('.box button.sign-button').click(function () {
    if (!checkedAlready) {
        // Do animation...
        checkedAlready = true;
    } else {
        location.href = "http://google.com";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `location.href="http://google.com";` should do the trick