# Setting cookie through PHP when Contact Form 7 submited

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form-7

I'm working on a landing page made with Bootstrap 4, Wordpress and Contact Form 7 plugin. In the page I have 4 buttons that when clicked show the same Contact Form 7 pop up form. I want them to:

1. Any of the 4 buttons clicked for the 1st time show the pop up with the form (already done).
2. When the form submited and any of the buttons clicked again (could be the same one) do not show the form, but start a download of PDF document.

I don't know how to design that better. I think that when the form is submited a cookie is set through PHP so I can check in each button if the form is done. Is it a good aproach? How should I set the cookie? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be redirecting the user to the PDF right after the form submission - there is [a simple guide](https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress-edu/redirect-users-contact-form-7) on how yo can do it. That could enchance the UX, users wouldn't need to understand that they need to click the same button once again.

Also, it could be easier because you would obviously want to change something after the actual event of sending the data (no matter how you track it). For example, you will not only need to add teh URL to the PDF into the button, but change the text and maybe even the style of it to make it obvious to the user.

However if you'd like to make it complex way - you can try changing the link on the button of form submission or adding the download link (or "enabling" it), while [disabling the submission button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53760658/how-to-disable-submit-button-and-change-text-on-form-submit-at-wordpress-contac) inside your form. Some examples on changing the link or showing/hiding contect can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134361/change-button-link-after-click) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155997/jquery-toggle-class-and-content-on-click-of-link) - all using the **jQuery**, no extra PHP needed.

Comment: Thanks that was really usefull I'll try one of your ways.

Comment: You are welcome, hope you find your very best way 